# Java core dump - free heap size not consistent with allocated heap

Tags: java, jvm, coredump, heap-size

One of my Java application crashed resulting in a core dump.

```
Java Heap Information 
-Xmx (Maximum Java heap size) : 1368m 
-Xms (Initial Java heap size) : 684m 
-Xscmx (Java class data sharing cache size) : 50M
```

but the core dump shows

```
Free Java heap size: 1.27 GB  
Allocated Java heap size: 1.34 GB

======================
0SECTION       MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1STHEAPFREE    Bytes of Heap Space Free: 516D2D48 
1STHEAPALLOC   Bytes of Heap Space Allocated: 55800000
=======================
```

How is it possible that  from the max heap size 1368m ,Free Java heap size is 1.27 GB and allocated Java heap size is 1.34 GB.

the Object(reserved) memory segment shows 100% utilization i.e (1368m)

Comment: java version used?

Comment: @FranMontero JRE 1.6.0 IBM

Comment: Maybe 'allocated' means 'commited' in this case... IDK

Comment: *"but the core dump shows"* - core dump is just a file on a disk, it does not show anything. How did you get these numbers exactly? Anyway, @FranMontero's assumption seems right: 1.34 GB = 1368m and this is exactly the total size of allocated heap (not the size of allocated objects in the heap). The heap itself is allocated in RAM, and the objects are then allocated in the heap.

Comment: @apangin  
the javacore txt file has below section that shows the heap space allocated and free.

1STHEAPFREE    Bytes of Heap Space Free: 516D2D48 
1STHEAPALLOC   Bytes of Heap Space Allocated: 55800000